# How to set customized release name in helmchart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After creating package in Helm , I am facing difficulty in setting customized chart name I tried below commands

```
> helm install --name example ./mychart --set service.type=NodePort 
> helm install happy-panda stable/mariadb
```

Also, tried commands from helm man page

```
> helm install -help 
> --name-template string specify template used to name the release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before setting your custom release name you've to check your Helm version . Above commands mentioned in question didn't worked in below Helm version

```
root@docker-slave:/home/mec/src/vmmanager/docker/vmmanager_chart# helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

For Helm 2 version.

> helm install --name your_customized_name chart_name

Like , helm install --name vmchart vmmanager_chart

For Helm 3 version,

> helm install   [--namespace ]  # Per-default you need
>   to provide a release name

For detailed description you can refer below link.

https://lzone.de/cheat-sheet/Helm